# Does sizeof operator cause templates argument deduction to occur?

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof

I know that `sizeof` operator doesn't evaluate its expression argument to get the answer. But it is not one of the non-deducted contexts for templates. So I am wondering how it interacts with templates and specifically template argument deductions. For instance, the following is taken from *C++ Templates: The Complete Guide*:

```
template<typename T> 
class IsClassT { 
  private: 
    typedef char One; 
    typedef struct { char a[2]; } Two; 
    template<typename C> static One test(int C::*); 
    template<typename C> static Two test(...); 
  public: 
    enum { Yes = sizeof(IsClassT<T>::test<T>(0)) == 1 }; 
    enum { No = !Yes }; 
};
```

This *type function* determines, as its name suggests, whether a template argument is a class type. The mechanism is essentially the following condition test:

```
sizeof(IsClassT<T>::test<T>(0)) == 1
```

Note, however, the function template argument is explicit (`T` in this case) and the function argument is a plan `0` of type `int`, which is not of type `pointer to an int member of class C`. In normal function template argument deduction, when `T` is really of class type and function argument is simply a `0`, deduction on `static One test(int C::*);` should fail since implicit conversion (0 used as null pointer type) is not allowed during template argument deduction and (I guess?) *SFINAE* should kick in and overload resolution would have selected

```
static Two test(...);
```

However, since the whole expression is wrapped inside the `sizeof` operator, it seems that passing the `0` without a cast works.

Can someone clarify:

1. if my understanding of function template argument deduction is correct?
2. if it is because of the non-evaluation nature of `sizeof` operator that makes passing `0` successful? And
3. if `0` doesn't matter in this context, we could choose any argument in place of `0`, such as `0.0`, `100` or even user defined types?

**Conclusion**: I found in *C++ Primer* that has a section on function template explicit arguments. And I quote "Normal Conversions Apply for Explicitly Specified Arguments" and "For the same reasons that normal conversions are permitted for parameters that
are defined using ordinary types (§ 16.2.1, p. 680), normal conversions also apply
for arguments whose template type parameter is explicitly specified". So the `0` in this question is actually implicitly converted to null pointer to members (pointer conversion).

Comment: Check Walter's Brown presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am2is2QCvxY

Comment: In the expression `sizeof(IsClassT<T>::test<T>(0))` the appropriate full specialization of `test` is used, and that's a function, not a function template. [Example at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9056a316b03a24a4).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf  So explicit specialization of function template doesn't cause arguments to be deduced? What if the explicitly specified template arguments conflict with what are passed to the function (say there are no conversions from the function argument types to the explicit template arguments)?

Comment: @Rich If the argument can't be converted to what's expected by one function, then that function doesn't participate further in overload resolution. This is just the usual rule about function overloading. The `...` matches anything, but is always the poorest match among possible matches.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Oh ! So if a function template has been fully specialized, no template argument deduction is done and template argument substitution(which may involve SFINAE) and overload resolution starts immediately after name lookup ?

Comment: @Rich: Right, no template argument deduction. Regarding what's regarded as "overload resolution" I'd have to check the standard. Parts of that are incredibly complex so it tends to slip out of my mind. I just use simple rules-of-thumb. ;-) If the code works with all relevant compilers, OK.

Answer (score 0):

Template Argument Deduction is done when instantiating a function. This is done as part of function overloading (and other contexts not applicable here). In TAD, the types of function arguments are used to deduce the template parameters, but not all arguments are necessarily used. This is where the "non-deduced context" comes from. If a template parameter appears in a non-deduced context within a function signature, it can't be deduced from the actual argument.

`sizeof(T)` is in fact a non-deduced context for T, but it's so obvious that nobody even bothered to mention it. E.g.

```
template< int N> class A {};
template<typename T> void f(A<sizeof(T)>);
f(A<4>());
```

The compiler isn't going to pick a random T that has `sizeof(T)==4`.

Now your example actually doesn't have a `sizeof` inside the argument list of a function template, so "non-deduced context" is an irrelevant consideration. That said, it's important to understand what "sizeof doesn't evaluate its expression argument" means. It means the expression *value* isn't calculated, but the expression *type* is. In your example, `IsClassT<T>::test<T>(0)` won't be called at runtime, but its type is determined at compile time.